# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined " in d3js map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, visualization

1I am working with d3js map. The below mentioned code is correct to my knowledge but it shows error i.e, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined " . Please help how can I solve this issue!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var canvas = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 760)
        .attr("height", 700);

    d3.json("nepal-topo.json", function(data){

        var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
            .data(data.features)
            .append("g")

        var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        var areas = group.append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class","area")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue");



    });


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is `data.features` an array?

Comment: Yes, it is . I am attaching the topojson file 'nepal-topo.json' file with this comment here.

Comment: {"type":"Topology",
"transform":{"scale":
[0.0008153473347334735,0.0004097297729772977],
"translate":
[80.048628,26.348908]},
"objects":{"nepal":{"type":"GeometryCollection",
"geometries":
[{"type":"Polygon",
"arcs":
[[0,1,2,3]],
"id":"Humla",
"properties":{"name":"Humla"}},{"type":"Polygon",
"arcs":
[[4,5,6]],
"id":"Darchula",
"properties":{"name":"Darchula"}},{"type":"Polygon",
"arcs":
[[7,-3,8,9,10,11,-7]]}

Comment: I don't see any 'features' property in the JSON: maybe you want to pass the geometries -  "data.objects.nepal.geometries" - or just the data as is "data"?

Comment: It does not work either.

Comment: The tutorial says that it should point to the name of the array like data.features in the tutorial because the name of array is 'features' in that json file. But I'm confused what is the name of the array in my json file. Any help?

Comment: Can you link the tutorial? To me it would make sense to pass the `data` object itself because it holds all the geometry variables. Try to pass `[data]`.